# Сохранение данных в облаке

Tags: java, база-данных, облако

Интересует такой вопрос: в моем приложении есть небольшая БД, которую хотелось бы хранить где-то в облаке, что бы потом можно было получать к ней доступ с любого устройства, пройдя аутентификацию, желательно с аккаунтом google.

Так вот, что мне нужно использовать для аутентификации используя google аккаунт и как прикрутить к приложению работу с облаком? Можете посоветовать, что стоит изучить (желательно более конкретное, приближенное к задаче), ибо я не очень понимаю, как это должно работать.

Comment: Глубоко не копал пока, но [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) смотрели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то ты все усложняешь, давай разберем задачу

1. надо хранить бд - как файл, в этом случае, он не отличается от текстового документа или фотографии. Если его надо защитить, надо делать свой сервер, на котором по данным аудентификации будет приниматься решение - отдавать юзеру или нет. Если БЕЗ своего сервера, тогда не получиться защитить его и это будет общедоступная линка, на ГД или дропе (кстати, если это дроп, то такое возможно только со старыми акками)
2. хранить базу как данные, лучше свой сервер, там где будет база, удобная админка и тд. Или удобно пользоваться BaaS сервисами.
3. зашить базу в assert приложения и обновлять ее с новой версией приложения

Comment: Окей. Вроде, понял, спасибо. С assert я не очень знаком, поэтому такой мини вопрос: записи в таблице постоянно изменяются пользователем. Я же смогу отправлять БД на Google Drive после каждого изменения или добавления записей в БД? Или обновлять БД при запуске приложения?

Comment: я думаю лучший для тебя вариант будет BaaS. могу посоветовать parse.com, хотя есть и много неплохих альтернатив

Comment: @Gorets, еще раз спасибо за информацию. Думаю, дальше справлюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Облако облаку рознь. У каждого облака свой API. Более менее общим является только аутентификация через [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) через него обычно поддерживаются все основные аккаунты.

Советую посмотреть в сторону [API Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java)

Comment: Ну, проблема в том, что не у всех пользователей есть акк. на Dropbox. Но я точно знаю, что у моей целевой аудитории 100 % есть аккаунт на Google. Тогда в моем случае мне нужно реализовывать аутентификацию с акк. Google+ и хранить данные на Google Drive, верно? Но тогда возникает проблема: пользователь будет видеть у себя на страничке Google Drive БД, что я залил, и сможет с ней взаимодействовать, что совсем не подходит. (И моржу понятно, пользователь может с этим кучу бед натворить). Так как поступить? Какой API использовать для хранения данных, если аутентификация происходит с акк. G+?